# PHPmailer mailer in herokku giving HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, email, heroku

I made a code that sends mail using SMTP gmail with phpmailer. It worked fine in my local host.But when I deployed the code in heroku it is giving

```
royalmarutiservices.herokuapp.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

Here is the log of heroku
https://pastebin.com/raw/AgY11dBB

```
<?php
//echo $_POST['email'].$_POST['fname'].$_POST['phone'].$_POST['subject'];
 include_once('PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php');
  include_once('PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php');
 $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();


    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP

    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = "user@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "pass";
    $mail->SetFrom($_POST['email']);
    $mail->Subject = " Message  from ".$_POST['fname'];
    $mail->Body = $_POST['message'];
   $mail->AddAddress('royalmaruti1996@gmail.com');

     if(!$mail->Send()) {
       echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
     } else {
       echo "Message has been sent";
     }
header('Location:index.php');
     ?>
```

Details about phpinfo()
~   https://royalmarutiservices.herokuapp.com/info.php

Comment: Posting your code here will help us help you, as well as providing the exact error message instead of a full dump. However, I see `include_once(PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /app/mail.php` in your log, so that's where you want to start.

Comment: @aynber the same code works fine on localhost but not on heroku server

Comment: https://pastebin.com/PpVWQFMP tree structure of program@aynber

Comment: @sivan is PHPMailer directory commited into repository? It looks like the PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php file is not there or is not accessible. Maybe you have it locally but it is not commited into heroku remote.